# How can I check if data successfully updated in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'd like to sent an email if only the data is successfully updated. What is the proper way to do that. I currently use:

```
$statusupdate   = $this->ModelComplaint->update($idcomplaint, $dataupdate);

if($statusupdate){
   //email code should be here
}
```

If the data fail to update then no email is sent.

Comment: I think what you have should work. Try changing a column name in `$dataupdate` to see `$statusupdate` getting `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

For Insertion or Updation in codeigniter. 
You can check it through `affected_rows()` function. 
You can use `$this->db->affected_rows()`.
So You can follow two options.

1) Option-1 :-

```
return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
```

2) Option-2 :- Simply Return ,

`return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0`

You can find more information on this link : http://henrypeteralbers.com/user_guide/libraries/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way is use transaction mechanism of codeigniter as below:

```
$this->db->trans_begin();//begins your transaction
$data =<data> //data for upadating
$this->db->where('id', $id);//where condition
$this->db->update('table_name',$data);//update query

 if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)//checks transaction status
    {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();//if update fails rollback and  return false
       return FALSE;

    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->trans_commit();//if success commit transaction and returns true
        //Send Mail here
        return TRUE;
    }
```

For more see here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html